If $(x-\lambda)^{2n-2}$ divides $\sum_{i,j}p_{i,j}(x)$, does it divide each $p_{i,j}(x)$?
I am working on a question about polynomials, and my aim is to prove that for each polynomial $p_{i,j}(x)$, $\lambda$ is a zero of order $n-1$. I have been able to get to the following expression:
$$\sum_{i,j}p_{i,j}(x)=(x-\lambda)^{2n-2}q(x)$$
where $q$ is another polynomial that does not vanish at $\lambda$. I know that this implies that
$$(x-\lambda)^{2n-2} \Big\vert \left(\sum_{i,j}p_{i,j}(x)\right)$$
I would like to conclude that $(x-\lambda)^{2n-2}$ divides each term of the sum. However, I am not sure I can do that. Could someone help me figure this out?

What is $p_{i,j}$?

$p_{i,j}(x)$ are a set of polynomials indexed by $i,j$

It is heavily dependent on what $p_{i,j}$ are (as @HackR mentioned). If there are no conditions imposed on them your statement should be wrong, since $p_{i,j}$ could be the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ multiplied with scalars.

Double indices are unnecessary here. Anyway, here is a counterexample:
$$p_{1,1} =(x-\lambda)^{2n-2} +1,  p_{1,2} =(x-\lambda)^{2n-2} -1$$
where $i \in \{1\}$ and $j \in \{1,2\}$.
